# gfortran debugging with gdb: w_powf.c: No such file or directory

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, fortran, gfortran

I have a Fortran program I am debuging. I have a list of varables and one of the expected variables is almost double its expected value. 
So I compiled the program, with debug flags, and commenced debugging:
the program name is hfock

```
$gdb hfock
(gdb) break hfock
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/e/Desktop/hfock hfock
Breakpoint 1, hfock () at hfock.f:16
16        ZETA1 = 2.173171
(gdb) s
17        ZETA2 = 1.188530
(gdb) s
18        WRITE (*, '( "Zeta1:", F7.4 / "Zeta2:", F7.4 )' )  ZETA1, ZETA2
(gdb) s
Zeta1: 2.1732
Zeta2: 1.1885
21        PLUS=ZETA1+ZETA2
(gdb) s 
22        PROD=ZETA1*ZETA2
(gdb) s
23        DIFF=ZETA1-ZETA2
(gdb) s
24        S12=8.*PROD**1.5/PLUS**3
(gdb) s
__powf (x=2.58287883, y=1.5) at w_powf.c:26
26  w_powf.c: No such file or directory.
```

The corresponding (24,25,26) lines of code are:

```
  S12=8.*PROD**1.5/PLUS**3
  T11=0.5*ZETA1**2
  T22=0.5*ZETA2**2
```

I think this might be a math library, or glibc related error, but I'm not sure what the error means, or how to fix it.This is fortran, why is it calling a C library? do I need to include a library? or install a missing dependency?
full program source here:
http://pastebin.com/waeEFSBZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`**` is in Fortran exponential operator. Exponentiation is implemented in glibc [w_powf.c](https://github.com/zerovm/glibc/blob/master/math/w_powf.c). Gdb can't find this file in your sources. This is not an error, rather diagnostic.

Comment: It says something like ../sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32/e_powf.c:69 on another line, but I don't see the sysdeps directory, or anything about ieee754 or any of it. where should I place the w_powf.c file, if i wanted it to be available?

Comment: what if you created ../sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32/ and placed file in there?

Comment: Ok, I go it. I installed glibc-source using the command: sudo apt-get install glibc-source and I got all the files that it was warning me about. Thank you for the help!
The path, to it is: /usr/src/glibc/debian/sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32

Answer (score 1):

The error means that the source file *w_powf.c* is not available on your system. It's not related to your program apparently. You can safely ignore that error.

Note that the lines you mention have the operator `**` which I suppose is implemented in that file, so it's just telling you that there is no access to the source code of the implementation of that operator.